# Is there a vehicle routing problem without time and cost constraints, whose objective is to maximize revenue?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, dynamic-programming

As the title states, I am curious as to whether there is a simple formulation to such a vehicle routing problem in integer programming. To be more precise, the formulation consists of the following variables:

a binary variable $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ for each potential stop $i$ that indicates whether the vehicle will travel past that stop, a revenue $r_i \gt 0$ for each stop $i$, and distance $d_i \geq 0$ from the starting depot, where the starting depot is denoted $0$ and final depot denoted $n+1$ for $n$ such stops.

In particular, the distance between any two chosen stops is strictly greater than $L$ kilometers, and the problem is defined by a route of $M$ kilometers, and that includes the $\textbf{starting and ending depots}$. For clarity, we assume that $d_1<d_2<\dots <d_n$ such that the stops are in order.

Some comments and suggestions are deeply appreciated. I apologize if there already exists such a formulation in a textbook or research article, but I just can't seem to find it.

$\textbf{Addition (since this post was unanswered for 3 days):}$

Over the 3 days, while thinking of such a formulation, I came up with the following formulation and also tried solving it by $\color{red}{branch-and-bound}$ and also by deriving a $\color{red}{dynamic}$ $\color{red}{programming} $ $\color{red}{solution}$ for the possible formulation. The model which I came up with is as follows
(adapted from the TSP problem - without including $M$ since logically a constraint that restricts each stop $i$ to be visited at most once means that no matter what, the length of the route will be at most $M$):

$$\begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            & \text{maximize}
            & & \sum\limits_{i=1}^n r_i x_i\\
            & \text{s.t.}
            & & \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \leq n-1 \hspace{15mm} (\text{since a subset of stops are visited}) \\
            &&& d_i - d_j > L \hspace{22mm} \forall i>j,    i=1,\dots,n,j=1,\dots,n\\
            &&& x_i \in \{0,1\} \hspace{24mm}  i=1,\dots,n
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}$$

So I thought of experimenting with some values, say

$\mathbf{d}=(d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5,d_6)=(3,5,10,11,13,15), \textbf{r}=(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5,r_6)=(110,80,150,115,200,110), M=25, L=3$

Are any of my formulations correct (do let me know if it is and if there are other possible formulations)? And how should I proceed by branch-and-bound (say using depth-first-search), and also solve it by dynamic programming?

Comment: You don't seem to have actually stated the actual problem in sufficient detail to determine what a correct formulation might be. Given the zillions of variations of VRP out there, simply calling it "VRP without time and cost constraints, whose objective is to maximize revenue" is not enough information to provide any useful answer.

Comment: @mhum I apologize for the lack of precision, but I realized I've made some errors in my formulation above. I have made some edits to narrow down the scope as well.

Comment: I still don't think this description is sufficient. You still have not stated *what* the problem actually is; a formulation is *how* you would solve a problem. Furthermore, even in the given formulation(s), there are strange things like the fact that you have not specified any intra-stop distances, only distances between stops and the depot. Is this problem one-dimensional (i.e.: do all the stops lie on a line)?

Comment: @mhum in my perspective, the intra-stop distances will be the differences between any $2$ stops, given by $d_i−d_j(>0)$ for $i≠j,i>j$. In particular, I've stated that in the question, and also in the second constraint. As for the next point you have raised, yes, the problem is one-dimensional as the goal is to find a path or route (which is essentially a line) that generates the greatest revenue. Note that only a subset of stops can be visited - for e.g. stops $1,3,5$ (since $L=3$ implies that the distance between any $2$ stops $d_i−d_j$ must be strictly greater than $3$).

Comment: It's still unclear to me if you are requiring that the distance between any two *potential* stops is greater than $L$ or if the distance between any two *chosen* stops is greater than $L$. In your first formulation, the second constraint encodes the former; in your second formulation, I'm inferring that you're trying to encode the latter (but it still doesn't work because what if $x_i = 0, x_j = 1$). Given that you are uncertain whether your formulations are correct, it may not be advisable to rely so heavily on the formulations themselves to convey what the problem you're trying to solve is.

Comment: @mhum Regarding your first question, the distance between two $\textbf{chosen}$ stops must be greater than $L$. I.e. for the numerical example above, stop $2$ cannot come after stop $1$ as the distance between these two stops is less than $L=3$. Furthermore, the stops are in order, which means that it is impossible to travel to stop $i$ after stop $j$ for $j>i$. To address your second question, correct me if I'm wrong, but if $x_i=0,x_j=1$, then the inequality does not hold as it will be less than $0$ (and $L$), so that case will not happen. I've updated my formulation accordingly for clarity

Comment: You have still not provided a full and complete description of this problem independent of any formulation. Given that you have framed this in the context of VRP despite the fact that there are significant departures from any VRP-style problem that I'm aware of would indicate that you should be more explicit. Furthermore, your formulations are unconventional in that they appear to encode constraints on the input constants (e.g.: $r_i$, $d_i$) which are not normally included as part of model formulations.

Comment: And, regarding the constraint $x_i d_i - x_j d_j > L$ for $i > j$, this would imply that if stop $j$ is visited, then every stop $i>j$ must be visited. Is that what was intended? I imagine not but I'm mostly inferring that from the fact that it probably doesn't make sense. By not providing an independent description of the problem, you are requiring the reader to make many assumptions about what your intent is via your formulations (which you do not know to be correct, as stated in your question).

Comment: @mhum I understand your concerns, but if I do not include the constrain $x_id_i-x_jd_j>L$, how then can I ensure that in all possible routes, the distance between any 2 chosen stops $i$ and $j$ ($d_i-d_j$) will be strictly greater than $L$? As of now, this constraint is my biggest concern. I shall remove the constraints $r_i>0$ and $d_i\geq 0$ as it is already defined in the question, for simplicity.

Comment: Your latest formulation will fail to find a feasible solution in your given example because $d_2 - d_1 < 3$.

Comment: @mhum If thats the case, what if in place of $d_i-d_j>L$, I have the two constraints: $x_i d_i-x_j d_j>K$ and $d_i-d_j >0$? Or is there any other way to ensure that the distance between any 2 chosen stops will be strictly greater than $L$?

Comment: wow bounty si0l. is the answer 42?

Comment: @hongsy If you are speaking about the objective value, then no. Note that the revenues $r_i$ are each way larger than 42, and that each $x_i \in \{0,1 \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will outline a problem that I believe is equivalent to the problem that the asker has asked.

We are given $n$ sites sitting on a line. For the sake of concreteness, let's say that they sit on the x-axis with co-ordinates $(d_i, 0)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots n$. We associate with each site $i$ a reward $r_i$. We would like to select a subset of these $n$ sites with maximum total reward such that no two selected sites are within distance $L$ of each other.

We formulate an integer linear program as follows:
$$\begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            & \text{maximize}
            & & \sum\limits_{i=1}^n r_i x_i\\
            & \text{subject to}
            & & x_i \in \{0,1\} \hspace{24mm}  i=1,\dots,n \\
            &&& x_i + x_j \leq 1 \hspace{22mm} \forall i,j \text{   s.t. } 0 <d_i -d_j \leq L\\
            &&& 
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}$$
This is sufficient to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your formulation! The constraint $x_i +x_j \leq 1$ is just what I needed! :) It all makes sense now. Just a question though - shouldn't we include also the constraint $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \leq n-1$ to ensure that a subset of stops will be visited instead of all $n$ stops?

Comment: Sure, you can add that constraint if you want. I didn't see where in the problem statement that you are prohibited from visiting all sites.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Since no one else gave an answer, I'll grant you the bounty then. :)